# Template web se angosta a medida que se abren ventanas modales

Tags: html, jsp

Estimados tengo un problema con una plantilla web que descargué y adapté a una pagina jsp.
El tema es que a medida que la utilizo , el ancho de la pagina empieza a disminuir y en unos 2 minutos de uso aprox, la pagina queda angosta.

Aquí imagen de como se ve al inicio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá imagen después de realizar acciones en la pagina.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se fijan cada ves que hago cualquier cosa en la pagina, se va angostando el extremo derecho.

aquí algo del código del template ya que es mucho código.

```
<html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="Free HTML5 Template by FREEHTML5.CO" />
<meta name="keywords" content="free html5, free template, free bootstrap, html5, css3, mobile first, responsive" />
<meta name="author" content="FREEHTML5.CO" />
<meta property="og:title" content=""/>
<meta property="og:image" content=""/>
<meta property="og:url" content=""/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content=""/>
<meta property="og:description" content=""/>
<meta name="twitter:title" content="" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <!-- Animate.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="webCliente/css/animate.css">
<!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="webCliente/css/icomoon.css">
<!-- Simple Line Icons -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="webCliente/css/simple-line-icons.css">
<!-- Magnific Popup -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="webCliente/css/magnific-popup.css">
<!-- Bootstrap  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="webCliente/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos_css/testtabsreserva.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/crearTramosv2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/calcularVolumen.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/fechas.js"></script>


    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/modalMisDatos.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/airExpressClientes.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/calcularMontoReserva.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
        mostrarReservasPorAjax();
        };

    </script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="webCliente/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilos_css/airExpressClientes.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" id="theme-switch" href="webCliente/css/style.css">

<!---PRELOEADER----->        
<style type="text/css">
body {
overflow: hidden;
}

#preloader {
position: fixed;
top:0; left:0;
right:0; bottom:0;
background: #000;
z-index: 100;
}

#loader {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
left:50%; top:50%;
background: url(imagenes/loader.gif) no-repeat center 0;
margin:-50px 0 0 -50px;
}
</style>

<style>
/* For demo purpose only */

/* For Demo Purposes Only ( You can delete this anytime :-) */
    #colour-variations {
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
    transition: 0.5s;
    width: 140px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 100px;
    z-index: 999999;
    background: #fff;
    /*border-radius: 4px;*/
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
#colour-variations.sleep {
    margin-left: -140px;
}
    #colour-variations h3 {
    text-align: center;;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #777;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;;
}
#colour-variations ul,
    #colour-variations ul li {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
    #colour-variations li {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px!important;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
    #colour-variations li a {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -ms-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.4s;
    -o-transition: 0.4s;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
    #colour-variations li a:hover {
    opacity: .9;
}
    #colour-variations li a > span {
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
    display: -moz-inline-stack;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
}
    .option-toggle {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: -30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background: #f64662;
    text-align: center;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
    .option-toggle i {
    top: 2px;
    position: relative;
}
    .option-toggle:hover, .option-toggle:focus, .option-toggle:active {
    color:  #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
</style>

<style>
 .inputs{
            width: 60px !important;
        }
</style>

<style>
 #modalConsultas
        {
            height: 800px;
            width: 150%;
            //overflow-y: auto;
        }


        #modalConsultaVuelo
        {
            height: 600px;
            width: 168%;
            position: relative;
            top: 50%;
            margin: auto;
            z-index: 1;


        }
        /*#modalConsultaClientes
        {
            height: 500px;
            width: 60%;
            //overflow-y: auto;
        }*/

       //#modalConsultaFolios
        //{
          //  height: 500px;
          //  width: 100%;
        //}
</style>

<style>
.modal-body {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);
    overflow-y: auto;
    }
</style>
<!-- End demo purposes only -->


<!-- Modernizr JS -->
<script src="webCliente/js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
<!-- FOR IE9 below -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

 <title>Air Express Clientes</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="preloader">
<div id="loader">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
    <header role="banner" id="fh5co-header">
<div class="container">
            <!-- <div class="row"> -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-header">

<!-- Mobile Toggle Menu Button -->
                <a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"><i></i></a>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fh5co-intro-icon icon-plane"></i> AIR EXPRESS</a> 
            </div>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="#" data-nav-section="home"><span>Home</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="Reservas" onclick="mostrarReservasPorAjax()"><span>Reservas</span></a></li>


                        <li class="dropdown">
<%
for(int i=0; i<usuarioCliente.size(); i++)
                                        {

                                            out.print("<a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' role='button' aria-haspopup='true' aria-expanded='false'>"+usuarioCliente.get(i).getUserUsuario()+"</i></a>");

                                            out.print("<ul class='dropdown-menu'>"
                                                    +"<li><a href='#'>Salir</a></li>"
                                                    + "</ul>");                                              
                                        }
%>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">

<%
                                //out.println("<div class='dropdown'>");

                                out.println("<button class='btn btn-secondary btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-user' type='button' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#exampleModalCenter'> Salir");
                                out.println("</button>");
                                //out.println("<div class='dropdown-menu'>");
                                //out.println("<a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Action</a>");
                                //out.println("<a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Another action</a>");
                                //out.println("<a class='dropdown-item' href='#'>Something else here</a>");
                                //out.println("</div>");
                                //out.println("</div>");     
                            %>

</li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
</header>

    <section id="fh5co-home" data-section="home" style="background-image: url(webCliente/images/full_image_2.jpg);" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
    <div class="gradient"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="text-wrap">
            <div class="text-inner">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                        <h1 class="to-animate">Bienvenido a Air Express</h1>
                        <h2 class="to-animate">Tu Sistema de reservas online para enviar tu Carga donde quieras <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/" target="_blank"></a></h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slant"></div>
</section>

    <section id="fh5co-intro">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-bottom-padded-lg">
            <div class="fh5co-block to-animate" style="background-image: url(webCliente/images/img_documento-instructivo.jpg);">
                <div class="overlay-darker"></div>
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="fh5co-text">
                    <i class="fh5co-intro-icon icon-bulb"></i>
                    <h2>Instrucciones</h2>
                    <p>Eres Nuevo ? Aqui encontraras los pasos a seguir para realizar tus envíos al destino que elijas de manera facil</p>
                    <p>
                                                <a href="archivos/ManualUsuario.pdf" class="btn btn-primary" download="Instructivo"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"> Descargar</span></a>
                                            </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fh5co-block to-animate" style="background-image: url(webCliente/images/img_reservar.png);">
                <div class="overlay-darker"></div>
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="fh5co-text">
                    <i class="fh5co-intro-icon icon-book"></i>
                    <h2>Reservar</h2>
                    <p>Aqui podras realizar tus reservas de manera facil y segura, ver Instructivo antes de proceder a realizar la reserva</p>
                                            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGenerarReserva"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"> Reservar</span></a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fh5co-block to-animate" style="background-image: url(webCliente/images/icono_mantenedorUsuarios.png);">
                <div class="overlay-darker"></div>
                <div class="overlay"></div>
                <div class="fh5co-text">
                    <i class="fh5co-intro-icon icon-user"></i>
                    <h2>Mis Datos</h2>
                    <p>Aquí podras editar y actualizar
                                            Tus Datos personales cuando desees , Recuerda que debes estar registrado.
                                            </p>

                                            <p><a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalMisDatos" onclick="verMisDatosAjax()"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"> Ver</span></a></p>


                                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>

    <section id="fh5co-testimonials" data-section="Reservas">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 section-heading text-center">
                <h2 class="to-animate"> <i class="fh5co-intro-icon icon-book"></i> Mis Reservas</h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 subtext to-animate">
                        <h3>Aquí puedes ver tu listado de reservas y su estado</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<form method="POST" action="">
<div class="left container-fluid">


 <div class="pull-right">

<%
              for(int i=0; i<usuarioCliente.size(); i++)
                           {
                               out.print("<b style='display:none'>User:</b><input type='text'value="+usuarioCliente.get(i).getIdUsuario()+" class='right' size='4' name='txt_usuarioVerReservaCliente' id='idUsuarioCliente' style='display:none'>");
                           }                        
    %>

</div>

<div class="panel-heading btn-info" > <i class="fh5co-intro-icon icon-book"></i> RESERVAS</div>
<div class="panel-body panel col-lg-12">
<nav class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center ">  
<div class="left container-fluid">

<div class="panel-heading bg-default btn-sm">MIS RESERVAS 
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" onclick="mostrarReservasPorAjax()" style="font-size:19px"></button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-plus" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalGenerarReserva" style="font-size:19px"></button>
</div>
<div class="panel-body panel panel-primary table-wrapper-scroll-y" id="resultadoReservas">
</div>
</div>
</nav>
</div>

</div>
</form>
</div>
</section>
<footer id="footer" role="contentinfo">
    <a href="#" class="gotop js-gotop"><i class="icon-arrow-up2">Inicio</i></a>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</footer>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="webCliente/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- jQuery Easing -->
<script src="webCliente/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<script src="webCliente/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Waypoints -->
<script src="webCliente/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<!-- Stellar Parallax -->
<script src="webCliente/js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
<!-- Counter -->
<script src="webCliente/js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>
<!-- Magnific Popup -->
<script src="webCliente/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="webCliente/js/magnific-popup-options.js"></script>
<!-- Google Map -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCefOgb1ZWqYtj7raVSmN4PL2WkTrc-KyA&sensor=false"></script>
<script src="webCliente/js/google_map.js"></script>

<!-- For demo purposes only styleswitcher ( You may delete this anytime ) -->
<script src="webCliente/js/jquery.style.switcher.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#colour-variations ul').styleSwitcher({
            defaultThemeId: 'theme-switch',
            hasPreview: false,
            cookie: {
                expires: 30,
                isManagingLoad: true
            }
        }); 
        $('.option-toggle').click(function() {
            $('#colour-variations').toggleClass('sleep');
        });
    });
</script>

<script src="webCliente/js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/testtabsreserva.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Aquí el codigo del servlet que muestra los datos en el div"resultadoReserva"

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    ReservasDao mostrarReservaClienteDao=new ReservasDao();
    //GuiasDao gdaoDisp=new GuiasDao();
    Usuario usuarioCliente=new Usuario();
    try
    {
        Connection conn = ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();

        usuarioCliente.setIdUsuario(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idUser")));
        ResultSet resultadoReservas=mostrarReservaClienteDao.verReservasCliente(usuarioCliente);

        ArrayList<Reserva>reservasCliente=new ArrayList<Reserva>();

        if(request.getParameter("idUser").isEmpty())
        {
            String errorVerReservasCliente="No se ingresó datos de entrada";
            request.getSession().setAttribute("errorVerReservasCliente", errorVerReservasCliente);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("errorVerReservasCliente.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
        else
        {

            while(resultadoReservas.next())
            {
                //reservasCliente.add(new Reserva(resultadoReservas.getInt("COD_SEQ_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("ORI_DOC_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("DES_DOC__RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getInt("TOTAL_PZS_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getDouble("TOTAL_KLS_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getDouble("TOTAL_VOL_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("EST_RVAS")));
                reservasCliente.add(new Reserva(resultadoReservas.getInt("COD_SEQ_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("ORI_DOC_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("DES_DOC__RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("ORI_VLO_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getInt("TOTAL_PZS_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getDouble("TOTAL_KLS_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getDouble("TOTAL_VOL_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("EST_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("NOTAS_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("FECH_GEN_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("FECH_EMB_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("TPO_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("PRIO_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("TPO_TFA_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getDouble("TARIFA_CNT_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("TPO_MONEDA_RVAS"),resultadoReservas.getString("RUT_CLIENTE"),resultadoReservas.getString("NOMB_CLIENTE"),resultadoReservas.getString("TEL_CLIENTE"),resultadoReservas.getString("DIR_CLIENTE"),resultadoReservas.getString("EMAIL_CLIENTE")));
            }
            request.getSession().setAttribute("reservasCliente", reservasCliente);
            //request.getRequestDispatcher("airExpressClientes.jsp").forward(request, response);
            PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<table class='table-condensed table-hover table-responsive' id='resultado'>");
            out.println("<thead class='input-sm'>");
            out.println("<tr>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>N° Reserva</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Origen</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Destino</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info' style='display:none'>Origen Vuelo</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Piezas</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Kilos</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Volumen</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Estado</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info' style='display:none'>Notas</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Fecha Creación</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Fecha Embarque</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Tipo</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info' style='display:none'>Prioridad</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info' style='display:none'>Forma Pago</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info' style='display:none'>Tarifa</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info' style='display:none'>Tipo Moneda</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Rut Cliente</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'>Nombre Cliente</th>");
                out.println("<th class='btn-info'style='display:none'>Telefono Cliente</th>");
                out.println(" <th class='btn-info' style='display:none'>Direccion Cliente</th>");
                out.println(" <th class='btn-info' style='display:none'>Email Cliente</th>");
                out.println(" <th class='btn-info'>Acción</th>");

            out.println("</tr>");
            out.println(" </thead>");
            out.println("<tbody class='input-sm'>");


                      try
                      {

                      for(int i=0; i<reservasCliente.size(); i++)
                                        {
                                            out.println("<tr>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getNumeroReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getOrigenReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getDestinoReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getOrigenVueloReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTotalPiezasReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTotalKilosReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTotalVolumenReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getEstadoReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getNotaReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getFechaCreacionReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getFechaEmbarqueReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTipoReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getPrioridadReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTipoTarifaReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTarifaReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTipoMonedaReserva()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getRutCliente()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getNombreCliente()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getTelefonoCliente()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getDireccionCliente()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td style='display:none'>"+reservasCliente.get(i).getEmailCliente()+"</td>");
                                            out.println("<td>"
                                                    + "<button type='button' class='btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-pencil btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalDetalleReserva' style='font-size:19px'></button>"
                                                    //+ " <button type='button'  class='btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-plus btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalAsignarVuelo' style='font-size:19px'></button>"
                                                    + " <button type='button'  class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-xs' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalReservaClienteEliminarReserva' style='font-size:19px'></button>"
                                                    + "</td>"); 
                                        } 

                      }
                      catch(java.lang.NullPointerException ex)
                      {
                          ex.getMessage();
                          out.print("</tr>");
                      }

            out.println("</tbody>");
            out.println("</table>");


        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

        }

    }
    catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException nullex)
    {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VerReservasClienteServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, nullex);
    }



}
```

Ahora está el código completo.
este template lo descargue de internet y funciona bien, pero si le agrego ventanas modales, al abrir la ventana modal la pagina se acorta y si se vuelve a abrir la ventana modal se vuelve a acortar la pagina y solo puedo recargar la pagina para que la pagina vuelva a estar completa.
por favor su ayuda, se que es mucho codigo pero no tengo una maqueta mas simple para explicar este tema ya que solo ocurre con los templates.

Comment: Te recomendaria maquetar una plantilla

Comment: tengo la plantilla de hecho la descargue desde Internet ,esta plataforma tiene como para subir archivos?

Comment: aquí esta la pagina del template https://freehtml5.co/elate-free-html5-bootstrap-template/

Comment: hola estimados, me podrían ayudar con este tema por favor, terminare de agregar el código ya que es mucho código el que tiene mi pagina, y el error es que al abrir una ventana modal, se angosta la pagina principal tal como indiqué en las imágenes.

Comment: hay alguna manera en css para mantener fijo el ancho de la pagina para que no ocurra eso?

Comment: Estimados ahora ya complete el código, por favor su ayuda. El problema es al abrir ventanas modales.